# Is constructing a simulated model for a fixed SNR possible in binary regression?

Tags: self-study, feature-selection, simulation, binary-data, overdispersion

When studying variable selection techniques like step-wise regression and the LASSO, a few studies employ a signal to ratio measure in order to control the amount of variability in a simulation. Specifically, if you have a model such as:

$$
y = X\beta + \varepsilon \\ \varepsilon \thicksim N(0, \sigma^2) 
$$

We can pin the signal to noise ratio, as defined below, to be fixed/parametrized by many different values of $\sigma$.

$$
SNR = \frac{{\rm Var}(f(X))}{\sigma^2}
$$

The quantity SNR is related to the percentage of variance explained (R2) in a normal regression model. The formulation of the problem so far comes from [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08692.pdf) and [2](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/hastieJSM2017.pdf).

Now, my question is: **is there an equivalent measure for binary response regression techniques?**

My intuition points at "no", for two reasons:

- since there isn't an equivalent notion of R2 in generalized linear models I wouldn't be able summarise error and explained variation as closely.
- in the typical formulations of glms for binary data, the common underlying distributions/link functions don't have a scale parameter, so there isn't a way of setting a fixed number for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Bernoulli variable, the variance is a function of the mean, so for binary variables the answer is no.  But if you pass to sums of binary variables (Binomial in the iid case), **overdispersion** is possible.  In binomial glm's (generalized linear models) overdispersion can be accounted for and estimated using quasilikelihood methods (in R, with the `quasibinomial` family function.)

But you cannot *simulate* from such a model, since there is no probability model underlying the quasilikelihood function. The best you can do is try some alternative distribution such as the negative binomial.

Comment: I'm thinking out loud now. But maybe one could simulate data from a negative binomial distribution and using the relationship between the negative binomial with the binomial distribution we could generate the binomial trials. All this while modeling covariates for the location parameters and fixing the relationship between the variance and dispersion parameter for the distribution.